# Connect Java with PostgreSQL: ClassNotFoundException: org.postgresql.Driver:Slankbank

Tags: java, mysql, sql

I keep getting this error message:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.postgresql.Driver:Slankbank
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:602)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:333)
    at Bank.Test.connect(Test.java:19)
    at Bank.Test.main(Test.java:8)
```

I don't know how to fix this.

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;

public class Test{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        connect();    
    }

    protected static void connect(){
        String hostURL = "jdbc:sqlserver://145.24.222.162:3306/eqod-log";
        String Username = "admin";
        String Password = "Slankbank2020!";
        Connection con = null;

        try {
            Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver:Slankbank");
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(hostURL, Username, Password);
            System.out.println("connection successful via ip address");
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Yes the libraries are imported.

Comment: check  your `classpath` or `path` contains  has the jar which have this class `org.postgresql.Driver:Slankbank`

Comment: What database are you attempting to connect to?  You've tagged it MySQL, your JDBC connection URL mentions SQL Server and your `Class.forName` appears to be attempting to load the PostgreSQL driver.

Comment: im trying to connect to a database that's called Slankbank.